# Wordpress Contact Form 7: Save form data in Session/Cookie

Tags: wordpress

I want to store the information already submitted by the user in a session or cookie. This information should than automatically be filled if the user again opens the contact form url. So the user does not need to enter again his name/mail etc

I already searched for plugins doing that... without success

Using Contact Form 7 and Wordpress